# Urban Airship Push Notification for iPhone: SSL Problem

Tags: ios, ssl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I want to use push notifications on iphone through Urban Airship, and i'm using their client library for iOS.

I integrated the library inside my project and everything compiles correctly.

On application launch, i'm trying to register my device token to the UrbanAirship server:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    
    //Init Airship launch options
    NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];

    // Create Airship singleton that's used to talk to Urban Airhship servers.
    // Please populate AirshipConfig.plist with your info from http://go.urbanairship.com
    [UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];

    [[UAPush shared] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [window addSubview:[self.firstViewController view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Now, I noticed that i'm getting the device token from apple, but when i'm trying to register it in the UrbanAirship server i'm getting error messages in the console from the UALOG about ssl problem:

*** Request ERROR [registering device token] 
Error: Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred: SSL problem (possibly a bad/expired/self-signed certificate)" UserInfo=0x2b2aa0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x2aedb0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -9807.)", NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure occurred: SSL problem (possibly a bad/expired/self-signed certificate)}***

I'm using the same certificate that I downloaded from the Itunes Connect.
Moreover, the cert seems to be OK when i'm accessing the APNs, so what can cause my problem?

(PS - The certificate is for development and so the UrbanAirship Application)

Comment: I found the solution. see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh god....

It appears that the solution is pretty simple:

The Date & Time settings on the device must be correct or the certificate won't be valid.

Apparently, if you wipe the device and restore it to factory defaults the time goes back to 1970's....

The Solution from [UrbanAirship support](http://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/60730-ssl-errors-and-the-api)